# Explain how a 'tox -r' works. It doesn't pull files from master different from .py

Tags: python, python-venv, tox

I have project, with the tox -r

```
[tox]
skipsdist = False
envlist = testenv

[testenv]
basepython = python3.7
alwayscopy=true
envdir = venv
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}/framework{:}{toxinidir}/pytest_plugins{:}venv/Lib/site-packages/
    PYTHONIOENCODING = UTF-8
    GITLAB_QA_URL=git+https://qa_tool_token:_token@git.domen.com/qa

deps =
    attrdict
    Faker==5.0.1
    luhnpy==1.0.0
    mimesis==4.1.2
    pytest==4.4.0
    requests
    selenium==3.141.0
    openpyxl
    google-api-python-client
    google-auth-httplib2
    google-auth-oauthlib
    bs4
    {env:GITLAB_QA_URL}/qa-api
    {env:GITLAB_QA_URL}/selenium-utils
    {env:GITLAB_QA_URL}/quack

commands =
    -python
```

It makes folder:
`project/venv/Lib/site-packages/qa_tools/api` and copy here all python files from master, but igonre non python files.
How to fix this?
project {env:GITLAB_QA_URL}/qa-api looks, like:

```
folder qa-api:
  folder qa_tools
    folder api
        __init__.py
        gmail_api.py
        credentials.json
        token.json
    __init__.py

  .gitignore
  .gitlab-ci.yml
  setup.py
```

What I already used. Add setup file in root project, like:

```
setup(
      data_files=[('', ['credentials.json', 'token.json'])],
     )
```

But it gives error:
`Python distutils error: "[directory]... doesn't exist or not a regular file"`

I have added in MANIFEST.in:

```
global-include credentials.json' 
global-include 'token.json'
```

I added in setup.pu another code:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='api',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=['api'],
    package_data={
        'api': ['api/credentials.json', 'token.json'],
    },
)
```

But python ignore setup.py with this code.

Comment: Before I could suggest any help to fix your problem, I need to know whether you develop an app or a library. Why do you set `alwayscopy=true`? Why do you use `envdir=venv`? The command `commands=-python` will just start the Python interpreter, and do nothing - is this intended?

Comment: @JürgenGmach, I develop auto tests on my job. I think, it looks like app.
1. alwayscopy=true, I want want copy files rather than symlinking, like tells here - https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html
2. envdir=venv, I don't know, just a legacy from my predecessor
3. commands=-python, I think so. As 2 two poin, just a legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

As you use `skipsdist = True`, you tell `tox` to not build a package, and so nothing can be installed into your virtual environment.

This means, neither Python nor JSON files will go into your chosen virtual environment, only your dependencies as specified via `deps`.

P.S.: I will update this answer as soon as I know what you try to do - see questions in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your directory structure

```
qa-api
    qa_tools
        api
            __init__.py
            credentials.json
            token.json
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

`qa-api` is just a development directory, its name is irrelevant. `qa_tools` is the top-level package and `api` is its subpackage. You don't have a package `api`, you have a package `qa_tools.api`.

Remove quotes in your `MANIFEST.in` and add relative paths:

```
include qa_tools/api/credentials.json
include qa_tools/api/token.json
```

Don't use `data_files`, it's for non-package data like application desktop icons. Generally not recommended.

For `package_data` dictionary the keys are full names of packages, `qa_tools.api` in your case; files must be listed with proper relative paths (no paths in your case):

```
package_data={
    'qa_tools.api': ['credentials.json', 'token.json'],
},
```

Documentation references: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute , https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: I edited as you suggested.
setup.py:
`import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    package_data={
        'qa_tools.api': ['credentials.json', 'token.json'],
    }
)`
manifest.in: 
`include qa_tools/api/credentials.json
include qa_tools/api/token.json`

But files with .json still doesn't copy.
Without any errors

Comment: I see the file `.gitignore`. Could you provide a repository (not necessary a real repo, just an [mcve]) for experiments?

Comment: Look, plz, I have tried to repeat work directory
https://gitlab.com/Galoperidol/testsetup.py

Comment: No `MANIFEST.in`, no `tox.ini`? Well, for this particular example: I added `package_data` to `setup.py`, created an empty `tox.ini` and ran `tox -r`; It works in the sense it installed `credentials.json` and `token.json` into `testsetup.py/.tox/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qa_tools/api`.

Comment: `python3.7 -m tox -r` also works, the files are in `testsetup.py/.tox/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qa_tools/api`. No problem at all.

Comment: MANIFEST.in and tox.ini are in another project.
Another project pulls project, which example I created, by tox.ini through setup.py

Comment: With my `package_data` this repository works for me.